# Rounded averages by group that sum to the same as the group total

Tags: r, dplyr, average, rounding

I have data that looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
                    
Data <- tibble(
      ID = c("Code001", "Code001","Code001","Code002","Code002","Code002","Code002","Code002","Code003","Code003","Code003","Code003"),
      Value = c(107,107,107,346,346,346,346,346,123,123,123,123))
```

I need to work out the average value per group per row. However, the value needs to be rounded (so no decimal places) and the group sum needs to equal the group sum of `Value`.

So solutions like this won't work:

```
  Data %>%
  add_count(ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Prop_Value_1 = Value/n,
         Prop_Value_2 = round(Value/n))
```

Is there a solution that can produce an output like this:

```
Data %>%
      mutate(Prop_Value = c(35,36,36,69,69,69,69,70,30,31,31,31))
```

Comment: Can you help me understand why the desired output has a value of 35 in row 1, a value of 70 in row 8 and a value of 30 in row 9? The data in the `Value` column are the same by `ID`, so you should expect to get the same output of `round(Value/n)` for each `ID`. Your code returns the mathematically correct values of the operation with no decimal places for `Prop_Value_2` for me.

Comment: @BenNorris If you take Code001 for example. The total value for that group is 107, however 36*3=108. So this means my crude attempt to proportion the group sum to each record leads to an overcount of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `ceiling` and then `row_number` to get there:

```
Data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(count = n(),
         ceil_avg = ceiling(Value/count)) %>%
  mutate(sum_ceil_avg = sum(ceil_avg),
         diff_sum = sum_ceil_avg - Value,
         rn = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(new_avg = ifelse(rn <= diff_sum,
                          ceil_avg - 1,
                          ceil_avg))

# A tibble: 12 × 8
# Groups:   ID [3]
   ID      Value count ceil_avg sum_ceil_avg diff_sum    rn new_avg
   <chr>   <dbl> <int>    <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
 1 Code001   107     3       36          108        1     1      35
 2 Code001   107     3       36          108        1     2      36
 3 Code001   107     3       36          108        1     3      36
 4 Code002   346     5       70          350        4     1      69
 5 Code002   346     5       70          350        4     2      69
 6 Code002   346     5       70          350        4     3      69
 7 Code002   346     5       70          350        4     4      69
 8 Code002   346     5       70          350        4     5      70
 9 Code003   123     4       31          124        1     1      30
10 Code003   123     4       31          124        1     2      31
11 Code003   123     4       31          124        1     3      31
12 Code003   123     4       31          124        1     4      31
```

Answer (score 2):

A first solution is to use integer division:

```r
Data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Prop_Value = ifelse(row_number() <= Value %% n(), Value %/% n() + 1, Value %/% n()))

# A tibble: 12 × 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
   ID      Value Prop_Value
   <chr>   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 Code001   107         36
 2 Code001   107         36
 3 Code001   107         35
 4 Code002   346         70
 5 Code002   346         69
 6 Code002   346         69
 7 Code002   346         69
 8 Code002   346         69
 9 Code003   123         31
10 Code003   123         31
11 Code003   123         31
12 Code003   123         30
```